# Bash - treat parameters as command parameters

Tags: java, bash

I know, that we can execute commands in a BASH using the `-c` parameter:

```
bash --login -c "command parameter"
```

Since we need to be able to execute any *command* with arbitrary parameters (that can contain spaces, quotes or apostrophes) programmatically (from Java), we would like BASH to treat all parameters as command, something like the `--` usually used to separate options from file names, e.g. with Git. Is there a way to execute the above call similar to

```
bash --login -<some option> -- command parameter
```

which could be executed from Java easily without escaping command or parameter?

```
new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {
  "bash",
  "--login",
  "-<some option>",
  "--"
  command,
  parameter
}).start();
```

Comment: Did you consider building a script (actual file) in Java and sending that to bash? It world be easier, and scalable to entire programs.

Comment: Yes, I've considered that, but it would be much more change (with possible encoding issues, too) than simply invoking a command.

Comment: You plan on using non Unicode (even ASCII) characters in the command your passing? That can be handled as well. In any case - could you give an exact example of something you want to run and breaks? I see you've accepted an answer, but commented it doesn't work for some reason? A concrete example would help clarify.

Comment: You are not "simply" invoking a command; ensuring that an arbitrary command in a quoted string is itself properly quoted is nontrivial, especially if the values of `command` and `parameter` are out of your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-c command` must be the last option argument to `bash`. Any subsequent arguments, whether or not they start with a dash, are assigned to the positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, ... in the shell executing the command.

That's usually convenient, since it lets you substitute strings into the command being executed without worrying about quoting them.

Since the first argument following the command is assigned to `$0`, it is very common to see invocations like

```
bash -c 'complicated command using "$@"' _ arg1 arg2 arg3
```

so that arg1 will be assigned to `$1` (thus allowing `"$@"` to work as expected, for example).

As an example:

```
new ProcessBuilder( new String[] {
  "bash",
  "--login",
  "-<some option>",
  "-c",
  "for arg in \"$@\"; do frobnicate \"$arg\" 42; done",
  "_",
  "first thing to frobnicate",
  "second thing", ...
}).start();
```

Comment: I've tried that now, but unfortunately, the Bash seems to split the parameters, so one parameter (of multiple) with spaces after the `-c` is treated as multiple parameters. :(

Comment: @ThomasS.: I tried it and it worked fine. Are you running on Windows? This sounds familiar to me, but I don't have a Windows machine to test it on.

Comment: I found this [workaround](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6468220?focusedCommentId=12149885&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12149885) in an old Java bug, which seems relevant and worth reading (although long). But since, as I said, I lack a windows machine, I can't really try it.

Comment: I've tried on OS X 10.11. Of course, by escaping the characters, it might be solved, but that's what I wanted to avoid, hence the question.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work on mac os x. Could you please edit your question with a specific example which fails?